# How to install a P-Trap with no offset and minimal horizontal travel

Tags: plumbing, sink, pvc, p-trap

Hey professional plumbers (of which I am not).

I am looking to replace the P-trap on a new kitchen sink install but I'm running into issues with the spacing for the p-trap. We are converting from a double sink to a single sink and I'd like to cap off the one drain on the left hand side and utilize the drain on the right side to maximize space under the sink. The sink drain is pretty much perfectly lined up with the stub coming out of the wall but there is only ~3" of distance between the stub from the wall and the center of the sink drain.

I was also attempting to replace the cheapo p-trap with a PVC trap, but that introduced sizing issues for me as well. I can't seem to find a configuration to make the trap, stub and drain work. If I cut the stub and replaced with a PVC trap, utilizing 4 fittings between the stub and the p-trap, I'm at roughly 11.5" in travel and I only have 9.5" from the wall of the cabinet to the center of the sink drain.

I feel like I'm missing something obvious (do I use 2 x 22.5 or 2 x 45s? and make it all wonky to work around the lack of travel I have? My current solution is to just replace and use the cheapo p-trap and cut off some of the stub to accommodate it, but I'd really like to get a more solid PVC trap on there to reduce chance of leaks.

Any ideas?

[image: Overview]
[image: Overview]
[image]
[image]
[image: Parts]
[image]

Comment: There is no advantage to a PVC trap here, and considerable advantage to sticking with a polypropylene trap. They are not particularly prone to leaks if properly assembled.

Comment: Would you just cut off enough of the stub to attach a threaded fitting on the end and stick with the poly trap then?

Comment: Could you not simply cap the right drain and use the left one instead?

Comment: I would probably add a 15 or 22.5 fitting at the wall so the trap outlet is NOT directly in line with the sink outlet, because traps are more easily adjustable that way using the full range of motion from the trap fittings. I also have no idea why you show a hub to MPT, FPT to hub, slip to FPT and MPT to slip in your PVC parts, other than if you don't understand normal reducers and/or unions? @Huesmann question states "maximize space under the sink" though if the left had a 90° to run along the back wall, that would be a minimal impact.

Comment: A slip trap adapter (which you already have)  is the fitting you want on the end of the drain pipe, not MPT nor FPT. If you really want to make your life miserable with PVC in the false belief that it will leak less, a PVC union.

Comment: I mean, the easy button is to just trim the stub cloer to the wall.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I am not a plumber. Perfectly capable of doing the work, but don’t have the experience with what I need to make it work. My thought process here was to replace the slip trap (poly p trap) with a PVC setup. I grabbed the fittings I thought I would need to go from stub to trap and then have a slip adapter for the portion that connects to the sink drain. Dimensionally I couldn’t get things to work though. If I went with using the left drain, would you put a 90 on the stub and then stick with a PVC solution for the trap and a slip connection to the sink drain ?

Comment: I’m probably over thinking it. I just like to take the chance to make it “better” when I’m at projects and this was one of those. If “better” here is just to avoid a S trap and not use flexible piping from the drain to the trap, I’ll stick with the poly trap and shorten the stub at the wall. If better is using the left drain or a 22 off the right drain and the pvc solution I’ll do that. Looking to crowdsource or have the folks who are smarter on plumbing weigh in. So thanks all for doing that!

Comment: In my opinion, as someone who does his own plumbing a lot, the only place I will use a PVC trap is when it's going under concrete and won't be accessible. Those are 2" minimum. As far as I'm concerned, plumbers put in glued-in-place PVC or ABS traps just to en$ure callback$ when someone needs to access the trap and finds that the only way to disassemble it is using a saw. I consider a polypro slip-joint trap superior for any accessible trap installation.